Dynamic parameter based on another parameter
I have 3 parameters. 1st parameter is text parameter with having 2 available - specified values like live date and inception date another 2 are date parameters - select live date and inception date range.
My expectation is When I choose the live date value in text parameter then select live date parameter should be enable and inception date should be disabled and similar like when I choose inception date then inception date range parameter should be enable, is this possible in ssrs?
